# Pathing in a non-geographic environment

Tags: mysql, algorithm

For a school project, I need to create a way to create personnalized queries based on end-user choices.
Since the user can choose basically any fields from any combination of tables, I need to find a way to map the tables in order to make a join and not have extraneous data (This may  lead to incoherent reports, but we're willing to live with that).

For up to two tables, I already managed to design an algorithm that works fine. However, when I add another table, I can't find a way to path through my database. All tables available for the personnalized reports can be linked together so it really all falls down to finding which path to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to try some form of an [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). Basically this looks at each of the possible next options to choose and applies a heuristic to it, a function that determines roughly how far it is between this node and your goal. It then chooses the one that is closer and repeats. The hardest part of implementing A* is designing a good heuristic.

Without more information on how the tables fit together, or what you mean by a 'path' through the tables, it's hard to recommend something though.

Looks like it didn't like my link, probably the * in it, try:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm
```

**Edit:**
If that is the whole database, I'd go with a [depth-first exhaustive search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Answer (score 0):

I thought about using A* or a similar algorithm, but as you said, the hardest part *is* about designing the heuristic.

My tables are centered around somewhat of a backbone with quite a few branches each leading to at most a single leaf node. [Here is the actual map](http://www.2shared.com/file/4053143/f955c523/dbMap.html) (table names removed because I'm paranoid). Assuming I want to view data from tha A, B and C tables, I need an algorithm to find the blue path.

Comment: I edited my answer with a more appropriate algorithm if that is a map of your entire database.